# apply pallete in geom_bar ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to apply a pallete to a geom_bar with facets.

Here is my code

```
est21 <- structure(list(Zona = c("Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural", 
"Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural", "Rural", "Urbana", "Rural", 
"Urbana", "Rural", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural", "Urbana", 
"Urbana", "Urbana"), Sector = c("Pública", "Pública", "Pública", 
"Pública", "Pública", "CECE", "Pública", "Pública", "Pública", 
"Privada", "Pública", "Privada", "Pública", "Pública", "Pública", 
"Pública", "Pública", "CECE", "Privada", "Pública")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(est21, aes(as.factor(Sector)))+
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, , fill = '#5081ac') +
  xlab('X') +
  ylab('Y') +
  facet_wrap(~Zona) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black'),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = 'gray'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = 'gray'),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                  size = 20),
        text = element_text(family = 'Sans')) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 7500)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count)))),
            stat= "count",
            vjust = -.5,
            size = 7) +
  labs(title = 'Proof')
```

I want a plot like this where the same pallete is used for the facets. [image: Plot]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Your formatting is hiding the first line of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) and realize that code fences (triple backticks `\`\`\``) must be on lines _by themselves_, so your `\`\`\`ggplot(...)` needs to be `\`\`\`` (or optionally `\`\`\`r` with the language-hint `r`) on one line, then `ggplot(...)` on the next line.

Comment: @Quinten the data is long, but I tried to post the first 10 observations.

Comment: See https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html#particular-palettes

Comment: @KevinSantos, for that you could do `dput(head(df,20))` for example?

Comment: @Quinten sure. I added in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [paletteer package](https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/paletteer) is a nice option as it makes many palettes available in one R package.

Use `fill = Sector` inside the `aes`, and add `scale_fill_paletteer_d("vapoRwave::jazzCup")` with the chosen palette.

(I excluded the `theme` lines just to simplify the example.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(paletteer)

est21 <- structure(list(Zona = c(
  "Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural",
  "Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural", "Rural", "Urbana", "Rural",
  "Urbana", "Rural", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Urbana", "Rural", "Urbana",
  "Urbana", "Urbana"
), Sector = c(
  "Pública", "Pública", "Pública",
  "Pública", "Pública", "CECE", "Pública", "Pública", "Pública",
  "Privada", "Pública", "Privada", "Pública", "Pública", "Pública",
  "Pública", "Pública", "CECE", "Privada", "Pública"
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  20L
), class = "data.frame")

est21 |>
  mutate(Sector = as.factor(Sector)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Sector, fill = Sector)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Zona) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 7.5)) +
  scale_fill_paletteer_d("vapoRwave::jazzCup") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count)))),
    stat = "count",
    vjust = -.5,
    size = 7
  ) +
  labs(title = "Proof", x = "X", y = "Y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way how we could do it:

1. We use `RColorBrewer` with `brewer.pal()`
2. We prepare the data with `count` and `mutate` before plotting.
3. This is because we want to use `geom_col` due to lack of knowledge of mine how to fill count stats in geom_bar()!.
4. After some modifications in the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

sPalette <- "Blues" %>% 
  sapply(., function(x) brewer.pal(4, name = x)) %>% 
  as.vector

est21 %>% 
  count(Zona, Sector) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Sector), y= n, fill=factor(n)))+
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  xlab('X') +
  ylab('Y') +
  facet_wrap(~Zona) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black'),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = 'gray'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = 'gray'),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                  size = 20),
        text = element_text(family = 'Sans')) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(freq, "%")),
            vjust = -.5,
            size = 7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sPalette) + 
  labs(title = 'Proof')
```

[image]